# Load file in imbedded JavaScript in Shiny

Tags: javascript, shiny

I am using a JavaScript plugin (http://www.biodalliance.org/) to display genomic data in Shiny app. However, I could not load the files.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Demo"),
    
    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
    HTML(
        "<script language='javascript' src='//www.biodalliance.org/release-0.13/dalliance-compiled.js'></script>
        <script language='javascript'>
  new Browser({
    chr:          '22',
    viewStart:    30700000,
    viewEnd:      30900000,

    coordSystem: {
      speciesName: 'Human',
      taxon: 9606,
      auth: 'GRCh',
      version: '37',
      ucscName: 'hg19'
    },

    sources:     [{name:                 'Genome',
                   twoBitURI:            '//www.biodalliance.org/datasets/hg19.2bit',
                   tier_type:            'sequence'},
                  {name:                 'Genes',
                   desc:                 'Gene structures from GENCODE 19',
                   bwgURI:               '//www.biodalliance.org/datasets/gencode.bb',
                   stylesheet_uri:       '//www.biodalliance.org/stylesheets/gencode.xml',
                   collapseSuperGroups:  true,
                   trixURI:              '//www.biodalliance.org/datasets/geneIndex.ix'},
                  {name:                 'Repeats',
                   desc:                 'Repeat annotation from Ensembl',
                   bwgURI:               '//www.biodalliance.org/datasets/repeats.bb',
                   stylesheet_uri:       '//www.biodalliance.org/stylesheets/bb-repeats.xml'},
                  {name:                 'Repeats xxxxx',
                   desc:                 'Repeats xxxxx', 
                   bwgURI:               'HSPC.bw',
                   noDownsample:         true}],

  });
</script>
</head>"
    ),
    
    HTML(
    '<div id="svgHolder"></div>'
    )
)
)
```

My personal data HSPC.bw could not be loaded, or even with www directory in my Shiny app. I really cannot find a solution to this problem.